# Scala Option if exists then set multiple vals if None set same multiple vals to empty string

Tags: scala

I have a Option employee object. From employee I want to get the name, department, address, number, age or anything else from it if it exists but if None the name, department, and everything else I want to set to "".

I would like to just do like in Java:

```
if (employee.isDefined) {
  val name = employee.get.getEmployeName
  val department = employee.get.getDepartment
  val address = employee.get.getAddress
  val number = employee.get.getNumber
  val age = employee.get.getAge
} else {
  val name, department, address, number, age = ""
}
```

but I learned it does not work like that. It looks like I would need another employee object and set the values like and then access it later:

```
if (employee.isDefined) {
  emp.setName(employee.get.getEmployeName)
  emp.setDepartment(employee.get.getDepartment)
  ...
} else {
  emp.setName("")
  emp.setDepartment("")
  ...
}
```

I also experimented with tuples?

```
val employeeInfo = employee match {
  case Some(emp) => (employee.getEmployeName, employee.getDepartment, employee.getAddress, 
                    employee.getNumber, employee.getAge)
  case None => ("", "", "", "", "")
}
val name = employeeInfo._1
val department = employeeInfo._2
val address = employeeInfo._3
...
```

Are these methods okay? Or are there any better ways to do this? Thanks for the help

Comment: So you want to go from `Option[Employee]` to `Employee` ? You can just do `employee.getOrElse(Employee("","","",""))`

Comment: That would work, but I made it more simple inside the employee object there is like a 50 different member variables so I would have to set all 50 of them to empty string("", "", "", "" ...). I just want to get 5-6 variables or else set them to empty string

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you need to rethink your design. It is not a good idea to set things to empty string like this, let alone have such a complex data structure with 50 fields. If you want to hand pick those fields you have no option but to do it manually. You could probably define a complex lens to aid you but it's not gonna be any shorter or cleaner than pattern matching. The only improvement you can do here is to collapse the value declerations to  `val (name, department, address, number, age) = employee match {...} `

Comment: I am trying to make an API where if the employee object exists it would show the proper values or else just empty string if not maybe I should have been clearer. I might just omit these variables altogether if null. Thank you for your suggestion I will look into it

Comment: The common practice is to return a `404 Not Found ` in that case. I have never seen an API return an empty object if it can't find the requested resource

Answer (score 2):

`.getOrElse()` is the usual means of extracting a value from an `Option` while specifying a default if the option is `None`.

In your case, however, it is the container of many values that might be `None`. For that I'd recommend `.fold()`.

```
case class Employee(empName : String
                   ,dept    : String
                   ,addr    : String
                   ,num     : String
                   ,age     : String)

val employee: Option[Employee] =
  Some(Employee("Jo","mkt","21A","55","44"))
//or  None

val name       = employee.fold("")(_.empName)
val department = employee.fold("")(_.dept)
val address    = employee.fold("")(_.addr)
val number     = employee.fold("")(_.num)
val age        = employee.fold("")(_.age)
```

But I have to agree with the comments from @sinanspd, your overall design is questionable at best.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle this specific operation:

```
val (name, department, address, number, age) =
  employee.fold(("", "", "", "", "")) { e =>
    (e.getEmployeName, e.getDepartment, e.getAddress, e.getNumber, e.getAge)
  }
```

But as suggested in the comments, it is worth looking at the overall design. For example it may be better to keep the values optional:

```
val employeeData: Option[(String, String, String, String, String)] =
  employee.map{ e =>
    (e.getEmployeName, e.getDepartment, e.getAddress, e.getNumber, e.getAge)
  }
```

This allows you to tell whether a value is `""` because `employee` was `None` or because the value in the `Employee` object was `""`. And you would probably define a different `class` to represent this restricted set of employee data to make the code cleaner and clearer.